# Luminosity effect in stellar spectral classification

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

“Atoms with  small ionization energy,Ir,will have a higher ionization in the atmospheres of giants than in those of dwarfs, and  the atoms with large Ir will behave in the opposite way. This theoretical prediction finds  support in the observational facts that the lines of Ca I (I.P. = 6.09 eV) and Sr I (I.P. = 5.67 eV)  are stronger in dwarfs than in giants of the same spectral class, while the reverse is observed  for lines of Ca II (I.P. = 11.82 eV) and Sr II (I.P. = 10.98 eV). Hydrogen lines serve as  interesting examples. Hydrogen has a sufficiently high ionization potential (13.6 eV). These  lines appear as much stronger in the dwarfs of classes B and A than in giants of these classes.  The reverse is observed in later classes K and M, where relatively stronger lines of hydrogen  appear in giants. Sr II at A 4077 serves as an important line for distinguishing between giants  and dwarfs. This line is stronger in giants than in dwarfs of classes F to M. The I.P. of  Sr being low, it is more easily ionized than atoms like Fe (I.P. = 7.87 eV) which remains  mostly neutral through these later classes. The ratio of Sr II (A 4077)/Fe I (A 4045) is sometimes  used to differentiate the luminosity effect”

The above paragraph explains the pressure effect using the Saha equation in the astronomy textbook.

My question is as follows. First, do giants and dwarfs with the same spectral type have different ionization ratios for certain elements? But look at the description below in the same textbook. For the same spectral type, it is indicated that the surface temperature of the giant is lower because the ionization ratio is the same.

“Again, we have seen that for the same temperature higher ionization is favoured in lower  gas density. This is illustrated, in Fig. 4.2. So since the atmospheres of giants are much rarer  than those of the dwarfs, and since the spectral classes are determined by the relative ionization  of a particular element or elements, it follows that the giants will have lower effective temperatures  than the dwarfs of the same spectral class.”

[image]

Finally, if the ionization ratios are the same for giants and dwarfs of the same spectral type, is the reason why the intensity of the absorption line is different because the temperature of the atmosphere is different in the Boltzmann equation?